# Iptables Block Subnets except Internet Gateway

Tags: router, iptables, dd-wrt, subnet

I have a Wlan Router
WAN IP 192.168.20.130(64port switch),
internal ip 192.168.1.1 DD-WRT Firmware.

The Internet Gateway is a Server in 192.168.20 Subnet, IP 192.168.20.254, an external Subnet is routed as 192.168.25.XX on same switch.

I should Block 192.168.20.XX, except 254 and 192.168.25.XX so all Clients on WLAN/LAN can surf but dont Ping and acess Servers in Subnets.

I tried:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.25.0/24 -j DROP 
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.25.0/24 -j DROP 
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.25.0/24 -j REJECT
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.25.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 192.168.25.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.25.0/24 -j REJECT

Comment: But i cant block Subnet 25 and accept all from 192.168.20.254 as Gateway.